# use apache avro as serialization protocol with amqp

Tags: apache, serialization, protocols, amqp, avro

There is any way to use apache avro as serialization library when heterogeneous applications communicate with each others using AMQP ? if it's possible links or examples will be very helpful.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer from the AMQP mailing list [here](http://markmail.org/message/tblg65geu5fhq7sy?q=avro%20list:org%2Eoasis-open%2Elists%2Eamqp-comment):
"I don't see any reason why not.  AMQP can carry any format of payload, including Avro's binary representation."